# How to select value from XML Column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following XML stored in an XML column (called XML_FORM) in a SQL Server table called Sub_FORM and I need to extract value (00006789) for 'txtOriginalIdFacility' field.

```
 <DynamicFormValue><GOVf1154><dataField><id>ucGOVf1154_MainForm</id><value /><tag /> 
 <visible>true</visible><history>|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /> 
 </dataField><dataField><id>rdoOption_NOI</id><value>false</value><tag /><visible>true</visible> 
 <history>false|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField> 
 <dataField><id>rdoOption_NEE</id><value>true</value><tag /><visible>true</visible> 
 <history>true|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField> 
 <dataField><id>rdoOption_NOT</id><value>false</value><tag /><visible>true</visible> 
 <history>false|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField> 
<dataField><id>txtForm</id><value>NEE Form</value><tag /><visible>false</visible><history> 
 Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField> 
<id>txtForm_F1</id><value>NOI Form</value><tag /><visible>false</visible><history>Form|3/7/2019 
4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField><id>txtForm_F2</id> 
<value>NEE Form</value><tag /><visible>false</visible><history>Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge|| 
</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField><id>txtForm_F3</id><value>NOT Form</value> 
<tag /><visible>false</visible><history> Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /> 
<comment /></dataField></GOVf1154><GOVf1154_NEE><dataField><id>rdoType</id><value>Initial 
Notification</value><tag /><visible>true</visible><history>Initial Notification|3/7/2019 4:41:15 
PM|Lge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField><id>txtFormerOwnerName</id><value 
/><tag /><visible>true</visible><history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LG||</history><description /><comment 
/></dataField><dataField><id>ucontrolFacility</id><value /><tag /><visible>true</visible> 
<history>|3/13/2019 11:12:01 AM|LP||</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField> 
<id>chkInternationalMailingAddress</id><value>false</value><tag /><visible>true</visible> 
<history>false|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LG||</history><description /><comment /></dataField><dataField> 
<id>txtInternationalMailingAddress</id><value /><tag>International Mailing Address</tag> 
<visible>false</visible><history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /> 
</dataField><dataField><id>ddlFacility</id><value>20000</value><tag /><visible>false</visible> 
<history>251750|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||</history><description /><comment /></dataField> 
<dataField><id>txtFacilityName</id><value>FB</value><tag>Facility</tag><visible>false</visible> 
<history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||#! (FH)|3/13/2019 11:12:01 AM|LPurvis||</history> 
<description/><comment /></dataField><dataField><id>txtOriginalIdFacility</id><value>00006789</value>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SQL Server has a bunch of XML functions - check the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to say "get the value for the id element where the parent dataField node has a id element with the value 'txtOriginalIdFacility'".  Use the `value` function to return a scalar value, and provide the full XPath query to find your element something like this:

```
-- Get the value element where the parent dataField node has an id element with the value "txtOriginalIdFacility"
SELECT XML_FORM.value('(DynamicFormValue/GOVf1154_NEE/dataField[id = "txtOriginalIdFacility"]/value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM Sub_FORM
```

A full test script using a table variable as an example:

```
DECLARE @Sub_FORM TABLE ( XML_FORM XML )

INSERT INTO @Sub_FORM
SELECT '<DynamicFormValue>
    <GOVf1154>
        <dataField>
            <id>ucGOVf1154_MainForm</id>
            <value />
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>rdoOption_NOI</id>
            <value>false</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>false|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>rdoOption_NEE</id>
            <value>true</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>true|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>rdoOption_NOT</id>
            <value>false</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>false|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtForm</id>
            <value>NEE Form</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtForm_F1</id>
            <value>NOI Form</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtForm_F2</id>
            <value>NEE Form</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge|| 
            </history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtForm_F3</id>
            <value>NOT Form</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history> Form|3/7/2019 4:40:49 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
    </GOVf1154>
    <GOVf1154_NEE>
        <dataField>
            <id>rdoType</id>
            <value>Initial Notification</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>Initial Notification|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|Lge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtFormerOwnerName</id>
            <value/>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LG||</history>
            <description />
            <comment/>
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>ucontrolFacility</id>
            <value />
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>|3/13/2019 11:12:01 AM|LP||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>chkInternationalMailingAddress</id>
            <value>false</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>true</visible>
            <history>false|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LG||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtInternationalMailingAddress</id>
            <value />
            <tag>International Mailing Address</tag>
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>ddlFacility</id>
            <value>20000</value>
            <tag />
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>251750|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||</history>
            <description />
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtFacilityName</id>
            <value>FB</value>
            <tag>Facility</tag>
            <visible>false</visible>
            <history>|3/7/2019 4:41:15 PM|LGeorge||#! (FH)|3/13/2019 11:12:01 AM|LPurvis||</history>
            <description/>
            <comment />
        </dataField>
        <dataField>
            <id>txtOriginalIdFacility</id>
            <value>00006789</value>
        </dataField>
    </GOVf1154_NEE>
</DynamicFormValue>'

-- Get the value for the id element where the parent dataField node has a id element with the value "txtOriginalIdFacility"
SELECT XML_FORM.value('(DynamicFormValue/GOVf1154_NEE/dataField[id = "txtOriginalIdFacility"]/value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @Sub_FORM
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Comment: Much Appreciated, it helped.